# Windows 11 network settings keep changing to static IP with blank configuration

Tags: networking, windows-11, tcpip

Dell XPS 15 9510
Windows 22H2 (22621.1485).

This problem has persisted through multiple Windows 11 updates and multiple Dell driver updates.

About half the time when I boot my laptop up at work, the wifi connection just says "No internet". It says it's connected to the correct wifi. Initially, I would just use the guest wifi or reboot a couple times until it worked. After finally digging, I've realized what is happening. The TCP/IP4 settings are changing to this somehow:

[image]

I simply change it to DHCP and it starts working. However, the next day there's about a 50% chance it will do it again. This is regardless of whether I shut down or just "sleep".

Comment: Run DISM / SFC, restart and see if that helps.  ......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Have you installed an antivirus (not Windows Defender) ?

Comment: Check with IT staff at work -- they may have implemented a Group Policy or network setting causing the issue.

Comment: No new antivirus installations. No new group policies or network changes. I'll try all the DISM and SFC commands and see how it goes.

Comment: It happened again this morning when I signed in. So none of the DISM or SFC tricks helped. I did notice "bridge driver" was enabled. The connection was NOT bridged, but I unchecked the bridge driver to see if that helps. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Booted up this morning to the same problem. I tried Windows 11's "Network Reset" which says "reset all network adapters to factory settings". It didn't actually seem to do anything, but prompted for a reboot. Upon reboot, same issue. IP was set to static but blank.

Comment: 1)[Reset TCP/IP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility-d954430c-9b11-43f0-6081-0fc9235a8b4a): `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` 2)Poke around Event Viewer: -Applications and Services, Microsoft, Windows, TCPIP; -WLAN-AutoConfig; -others I can't think of lol

Comment: Have you tried this kind of command : `netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet0" dhcp`. You may also try the matching PowerShell command `Get-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet0 | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Enabled`. Question: Have you installed JumpStart WiFi?

Comment: Does this only happen on wifi? Have you tried updating wifi drivers? I would also check for any scheduled jobs, just in case.

Comment: @THEJOATMON: Have you abandoned your post?

Comment: Sorry, I was traveling. It actually hasn't done this at all in the last 3 days since I've been back to the office (the only place it happens). If it happens again I will try some of the ideas in the comments above.

Comment: To address a couple questions: "Does it only happen on wifi?" I don't know, I never use this laptop wired. "Have you installed JumpStart WiFi?" No, never even heard of it.

Comment: You may try the above commands (they can't hurt), and if this remains stable for a few weeks, come back and report.

Comment: If I try the commands now, not knowing if I'm still having the issue or not, results would be inconclusive. There would be no point in reporting back to say "I ran these commands and I still don't have the problem".

Answer (score 0):

I've run with the same issue on Windows 10 22H2.
After assigning IP details manually on the Ethernet port it showed blank settings just the same way as on the picture in this post.
Network reset didn't help, however after running 'ipconfig' I've discovered that coincidentally the same IP was assigned on the WiFi adapter.
Thus, after assigning IP details from another subnet, the IP settings were saved successfully.